# How to make a bootable USB to run a Python script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm **not** trying to make a script that creates a bootable USB. 
I'm making a password recovery program.

Now what I would like to do is have a **bootable USB that would, once booted, run a python script.**

It's simple as that (or is it?). I didn't try anything yet because I don't know how to do it and I didn't find much about this.

I was thinking of using some minimal linux distro (Such as Damn Small Linux, ~50mb), install python and run the script.

Anyone knows something about this? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention: 
Windows 10 Pro
Python 3.4 (Anaconda3 distribution)

Comment: Can you provide additional context? I can't tell whether these passwords you're recovering are on your machine or on machines that belong to other people, or (if the latter) whether those people will be aware that their passwords are being "recovered."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm trying to do this on my computer. I have my password rememberd but I saw this idea on some website (can't remember) You basicly change the password using some system recovery trick that Microsoft hasen't patched since like XP. (And I would never use it on someone elses computer, not even with their permission, don't wanna screw somthing up)

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should be about a narrow, specific problem. There are tens of technical decisions you would need to make before reaching the point of having a narrow, specific problem here -- picking an embedded distro, picking an init system (if any), deciding which bootloaders you're going to support (UEFI? Legacy BIOS? ...), etc etc etc. Once you've gotten far enough to have actually _encountered a specific problem_, then there might be an on-topic question here.

Comment: (personally, when I want to build a dedicated-purpose embedded system image, I reach for Buildroot or NixOS, each of which provides excellent tools for the purpose; but they're very different tools, and one would hit different roadblocks taking each path).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) to bundle your python script with all its dependencies to include with the USB OS.  This might help with the configuration.  You should be able to install the OS on the USB and then just copy over the cx_freeze directory and not have to worry about installing modules on the base OS

Comment: This is bad advice: `cx_freeze` (and similar tools like pyinstaller) create a self-extracting executable that then needs to be extracted into tmpfs at runtime. This means you're increasing your RAM requirements to store everything that was extracted on tmpfs while your target system is booted -- whereas if you just have a regular Python runtime inside your embedded system image and store that image on a read-only filesystem like squashfs, the OS can discard pages from RAM whenever memory is tight and reload them from the filesystem if they're ever needed again.